# Class file somehow not allowing multi-page deluxetable to fill each page

Tags: tables, margins, deluxetable

Working with a thesis class file, I find that my multi-page deluxetables are not permitted to fill the margins all the way, but instead fill only about half the height of the page, and maybe ~2/3 of the area allowed by the margins.  Because of the complexity in my table formatting (more complex than the MWE I show here), I really need to stick with deluxetable rather than converting to a more normal LaTeX table format.

When I switch to the normal article class my tables work just fine.

One possibly relevant piece is that when I compile my document, I get a warning

> ! Undefined control sequence.
>   l.12 \startlongtable

I find this frustrating because I'm using almost the same [deluxetable environment available from NASA](https://fits.gsfc.nasa.gov/standard30/deluxetable.sty) (only one line commented out in mine, line 299) but am adding the `\startlongtable` command [based on the AASTeX v6.3 instructions](https://journals.aas.org/aastexguide/) for multi-page tables but it seems the NASA-provided file is now out of date and does not have \startlongtable implemented.

So basically, I don't know whether the fundamental issue is my not having `\startlongtable` defined (but still telling LaTeX to go ahead with compilation anyway, which it does) or whether it's something in the class file I am using.

**Edit:** I noticed that even tables I haven't explicitly set to be multi-page tables via `\startlongtable` are also breaking up over pages, about the same size as the other tables.

MWE:

First the class file, thesismod.cls, which I cut a bunch of stuff out of from the original.  I find that removing either `\doublespacing` or `\makelot` makes the table fill up the page within the margins.

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{thesismod}
\RequirePackage{setspace}
\newcommand*{\mainmatter}{\pagenumbering{arabic}}
\newcommand*{\makelot}{}
\newcommand*{\begincmd}{
\doublespacing
\makelot
\clearpage\mainmatter}

\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{report}}
\ProcessOptions
%% Not necessary to specify the point size - we inherit it from above
% \LoadClass[12pt]{report}
\LoadClass{report}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{.5in}   %{.4375in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{.5in} %{.4375in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-.5in}  %{-.5625in}
\setlength{\textheight}{9in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6in}
\AtBeginDocument{\begincmd}
\endinput
```

As mentioned, the `deluxetable.sty` is the same file as available from NASA with line 299 commented out.

And my main file:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{thesismod}

\usepackage{deluxetable}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\startlongtable
\begin{deluxetable}{c}
\tablewidth{0pc}
\tabletypesize{\scriptsize}
\tablecolumns{10}
\tablecaption{Title}
\tablehead{\colhead{ID }}
\startdata
W491 \\W508 \\W521 \\W566\\W689\\W799 \\W837 \\W869 \\W1091 \\W1154\\W1165 \\W1349\\W1582\\W1601 \\W1608 \\W1735 \\W1763 \\W1848 \\W1912 \\W1978 \\W2005 \\W2015 \\W2162 \\W2386 \\W2631 \\W2665 \\W2678 \\W2740 \\W2772 \\W2887 \\W2951 \\W3014 \\W3033 \\W3070 \\W3073 \\W3114 \\W3259 \\W3407 \\W3430 \\W3480 \\W3485 \\W3742 \\W3957 \\W3996 \\W4081 \\W4237 \\W4333 \\W4361 \\W4490 \\W58 \\W267 \\W371 \\W435 \\W461 \\W829 \\W901 \\W920 \\W1056 \\W1068 \\W1208 \\W1222 \\W1263 \\W1539 \\W1717 \\W1725 \\W1809 \\W1834 \\
\enddata
\end{deluxetable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Regarding "... I don't know whether the fundamental issue is my not having \startlongtable defined (but still telling LaTeX to go ahead with compilation anyway, ...: Please never ever ignore error messages! Even if you get something that on first glance resembles a pdf file, there can still be issues with it. After an error, TeX only tries to recover enough to syntax check more of the file, it does not try to make sensible output after an error.

Answer (score 1):

I found that encasing the table in a single space environment worked.  Also I dropped the `\startlongtable` since it wasn't doing anything as an undefined command.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{thesismod}

\usepackage{deluxetable}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\begin{singlespace}
\begin{deluxetable}{c}
\tablewidth{0pc}
\tabletypesize{\scriptsize}
\tablecolumns{10}
\tablecaption{Title}
\tablehead{\colhead{ID }}
\startdata
W491 \\W508 \\W521 \\W566\\W689\\W799 \\W837 \\W869 \\W1091 \\W1154\\W1165 \\W1349\\W1582\\W1601 \\W1608 \\W1735 \\W1763 \\W1848 \\W1912 \\W1978 \\W2005 \\W2015 \\W2162 \\W2386 \\W2631 \\W2665 \\W2678 \\W2740 \\W2772 \\W2887 \\W2951 \\W3014 \\W3033 \\W3070 \\W3073 \\W3114 \\W3259 \\W3407 \\W3430 \\W3480 \\W3485 \\W3742 \\W3957 \\W3996 \\W4081 \\W4237 \\W4333 \\W4361 \\W4490 \\W58 \\W267 \\W371 \\W435 \\W461 \\W829 \\W901 \\W920 \\W1056 \\W1068 \\W1208 \\W1222 \\W1263 \\W1539 \\W1717 \\W1725 \\W1809 \\W1834 \\
\enddata
\end{deluxetable}
\end{singlespace}

\end{document}
```